# Music player app not working on android 10

Tags: android-music-player, android-10.0

I'm working on a music player and it works on android phones running api 23 - 28 but when I try it on a phone running api 29 the app doesn't play any music.

This is the logcat.

```
avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=20989 comm="libwatcher_bina" name="file-nr" dev="proc" ino=17570315 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_27:s0:c209,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:proc:s0 tclass=file permissive=0 SEPF_SM-N970U1_10_0006 audit_filtered
```

Does anyone know how to get it to work

Comment: What does your code look like?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem had to add - android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" - to Manifest file under application tag.